# Are ISO-8858-1 entities like &#248; to represent 'ø' valid when page is otherwise encoded as UTF-8?

Tags: html, character-encoding

Say we have a site that returns a HTTP header like this:

```
text/html; charset=utf-8
```

And the (redacted) source contains:

```
<title>Weird char: &#248;</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Is that valid HTML? This is clearly a UTF-8 encoded page, and `&#248;` is the ISO-8851-1 entity for `ø` also called `&oslash;`.

I'm not asking whether using `&oslash;` or even a raw UTF-8-encoded `ø` would've been better (it would) - but I'm asking whether the HTML entity `&#248;` is valid on a UTF-8-encoded page.

Both Chrome and Firefox show the page fine, and https://validator.w3.org also doesn't complain.

Comment: I would expect them to work. Here is a more elaborate discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922342/charset-utf8-and-character-entities

Comment: And don't call oslash weird when you have one in your own name ;))) Er det forstået?

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is a superset of Latin-1 (which it is a superset of ASCII) (for the relation numeric value to grapheme. So every codepoint of ASCII and Latin1 keep the same codepoint in unicode, so you can use the same construct and the same value.

But this works only for Latin1 and ASCII